# I can't understand why my output is 1,1 how can I change it to "type name" and "parameters"? TIA

Tags: c++, function

I'm just new at c++ and I'm reading about functions but now I'm trying to use string but I really can't understand it. how can I show the 
"type name" and "parameters" in my output? here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string f1 (string a)
{
    string b;
    b = " type name ";
    return (b);
}

string f2 (string c)
{
    string d;
    d = " parameters ";
    return (d);
}

int main ()
{
    string x,y;
    x = f1(" type name ");
    y = f2(" parameters ");
    cout<<"Functions is a group of statements that executed"<<endl;
    cout<<"when it is called. It is consist of"<< x <<","<< y <<endl;
    cout<<"and a statement. It can be called to some some point of the program."<<endl;

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: `x` and `y` are strings. `f1` and `f2` are functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout<<"when it is called. It is consist of"<< f1 <<","<< f2 <<endl;
```

`f1` and `f2` are functions. You don't want to output the functions, you want to output the *result of calling* the functions.

```
x = f1(" type name ");
y = f2(" parameters ");
```

You have stored the result of the calls in `x` and `y`, so use those.

```
cout<<"when it is called. It is consist of"<< x <<","<< y <<endl;
//                                            ^         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
cout<<"when it is called. It is consist of"<< f1 <<","<< f2 <<endl;
```

To this:

```
cout<<"when it is called. It is consist of"<< x <<","<< y <<endl;
```

However, you have redundancy in your code.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do ,

```
string f1 (string a)
string f2 (string c)
```

accepts a string but you not doing anything withit, in the main you are calling the function with the string you never used internally.

Are you trying to use,

```
string f1 ()
string f2 ()
```

and use this

```
cout<<"when it is called. It is consist of"<< x <<","<< y <<endl;
```

you are trying to print the strings right not the functions